# How to download tar file on internet through Linux shell?

Tags: linux, download, putty

I've been trying to download a tar file from the internet on a remote machine using Linux (and PuTTY), but nothing has been working for me. I was able to download it on my Windows laptop, but I can't figure out how to either transfer from my laptop to the remote machine or just download it from PuTTY. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Regarding the transfer between your laptop and to the remote machine, I believe you are looking for [`scp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp).

Comment: Take a look at `wget`: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/the-ultimate-wget-download-guide-with-15-awesome-examples/

Comment: Since you're using putty, try the psftp utility that comes with it.